# QRegexp idiosyncracies (compared to perl): How can I write this regexp without the lazy quantifier?

Tags: regex, qt

I have the following regular expression that works fine in perl:

```
Classification:\s([^\n]+?)(?:\sRange:\s([^\n]+?))*(?:\sStructural Integrity:\s([^\n]+))*\n
```

The type of data format this string is supposed to match against is:

```
Classification: Class Name     Range: xxxx     Structural Integrity: value
Classification: Class Name    Structural Integrity: value
Classification: Class Name
```

That is: the "Range" and "Structural Integrity" fields are optional. So the desired result is:

```
{
$& [Classification: Class Name Range: xxxx Structural Integrity: value ]
$1 [Class Name ]
$2 [xxxx ]
$3 [value ]

$& [Classification: Class Name    Structural Integrity: value ]
$1 [Class Name ]
$2 [value ]

$& [Classification: Class Name ]
$1 [Class Name ]
}
```

The expression uses the ? lazy quantifier in two places. This operator is not supported by QRegExp, instead Qt uses a "minimal" property which, when set to true, makes **all** quantifiers in an expression *non-greedy*

Armed with this information I write my code:

```
QRegExp rx("Classification:\\s([^\\n]+)(?:\\sRange:\\s([^\\n]+))*(?:\\sStructural Integrity:\\s([^\\n]+))*\\n");
rx.setMinimal(true);
```

But the results are incorrect, and after much tweaking I haven't been able to get the correct captures. Is it possible to split this up into more code and less regex? Or to rewrite it without the lazy operator?

Comment: Nope not Star Trek.. but it is space related ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
QRegExp rx("(Classification|Range|Structural\\s+Integrity):|(\\S+)");
QStringList classification();
QStringList range();
QStringList integrity();

QStringList current = null;

int pos;
while ((pos = rx.indexIn(str, pos)) != -1) {
    if (rx.cap(1) == null) {
        if (current != null) {
            current << rx.cap(2);
        }
    }
    else if ("Classification".equals(rx.cap(1))) {
       current = classification;
    }
    else if ("Range".equals(rx.cap(1))) {
       current = range;
    }
    else if ("Structural Integrity".equals(rx.cap(1))) {
       current = integrity;
    }
    pos += rx.matchedLength();
}
```

It matches either valid keys followed by a colon or words. If it is a key, change the current list to the corresponding one. Otherwise add the word to the current list.

In the end, you will have the lists `classification`, `range` and `integrity`, containing the words after the corresponding keys. You could join them after the full match is done:

```
QString classificationString = classification.join(" ");
```

It does not care about the order of the keys though.

Answer (score 0):

Also there is [**QRegExp::RegExp2**](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qregexp.html#PatternSyntax-enum) that supports greedy quantifiers since 4.2